# when calling the api from server i am able to see the response but when using data.map() to iterate the data is not display in frontend in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

when calling the API  from server I am able to see the response but when using `data.map()` to iterate the data is  not reflected in frontend in the next js

First I called the API from the server side and I was able to see the response .but when I try to iterate the data using the map function I am not able to see the data and there is no error.

Here is my code.

```
async function productlist(){
  
  let data = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/users`);
   data = await data.json();
  return data;
}

export default async function Home() {

  let data = await productlist();
  console.log("dataArr",data);
  console.log("dataArr",data[0].urls.small);
 
  return (
    
       <div>
      {/*<!-- Featured section -->*/}
<section className="py-20">
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-800 mb-8">Free Stock Photos</h2>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-8">

            {
              data.map((product)=>{
                <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden opacity-100 hover:opacity-80 transition duration-500 ease-in-out">
                <img src={product.firstName} alt="Coffee"
                    className="w-full h-full object-cover"/>        
                <h2>{product.firstName}</h2>      
                
            </div>

            })}
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: I want to populate the name of the user. Please ignore the image tag in which i had used wrong src. I have also tried by removing the image tag but still it is not working

Comment: No,I want to populate 30 users name thats why i have used map function to fetch all the names.

Comment: @NaveenNizam Thank you for the code. But the code that you have given is client side and i want the data to be shown from server side

Comment: @MrunalSolkar have a look to my suggestion

Comment: @NaveenNizam Yes

Comment: @Hatana  After passing the return inside map function it is working now. Thank you for the help. But can you tell. I have also work in react. In react i have never used the return inside the map function but still I am able to see the data in frontend. So why we need to add return in nextjs.

Comment: @MrunalSolkar the code here is all React if you are familiar with the implicit return you don't have to put the `return` keyword but also you shouldn't put curly braces too `{}` so it is either `=>(<div>..</div>)` or `=>{ return (<div>..</div>) }` there is no between

Answer (score 0):

your `.map` function is not returning anything.

you either have use an explicit return:

```
data.map((product, index) => {
  return (
    <div
      key={index}
      className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden opacity-100 hover:opacity-80 transition duration-500 ease-in-out"
    >
      <img src={product.firstName} alt="Coffee" className="w-full h-full object-cover" />
      <h2>{product.firstName}</h2>
    </div>
  );
});
```

or an implicit return:

```js
data.map((product, index) => (
  <div
    key={index}
    className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden opacity-100 hover:opacity-80 transition duration-500 ease-in-out"
  >
    <img src={product.firstName} alt="Coffee" className="w-full h-full object-cover" />
    <h2>{product.firstName}</h2>
  </div>
));
```

Have a look [here](https://waylonwalker.com/explicit-vs-implicit-returns-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Often%20when%20reading%20through%20javascript,require%20an%20explicit%20return%20statement.)

**Note:** when using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) inside JSX you have always to specify a unique `key` for each element of the returned array.